# Samsung Galaxy SM-R800 Gear S4 location permission error (TIZEN_ERROR_PERMISSION_DENIED)

Tags: cllocationmanager, tizen, tizen-native-app

I'm trying to get the location of Samsung Galaxy SM-R800 Gear S4. Following the official [documentation](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4.0/org.tizen.tutorials/html/native/location/location_tutorial_n.htm) of Tizen, I'm unable to get the location and it says TIZEN_ERROR_PERMISSION_DENIED. I allowed all the required permissions from the watch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That documentation looks quite old. Your watch runs on Tizen 4.0, so please refer to the right guide and examples.

Since Tizen 4.0, applications should acquire privacy-related permissions by prompting the user for a choice. Please check out the following documentation and configure your application to have such logic (`ppm_check_permission()` and `ppm_request_permission()`).

- https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/security/privacy-related-permissions (for native applications)
- https://docs.tizen.org/application/dotnet/guides/security/requesting-permissions (for .NET applications)
- https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/tutorials/details/sec-privileges (a list of privileges)

Comment: Hey Swift, Thank you for the response. followed the documentation. To some extent the problem is solved, I'm getting permission from the watch, The location manager starts perfectly, but `location_manager_get_last_location` function exits with error decimal code -46137341. And the callback function is not called.
I couldn't figure out what this error is.

Comment: The error code corresponds to [`LOCATIONS_ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE`](https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/api/wearable/4.0/group__CAPI__LOCATION__MANAGER__MODULE.html#ga37b784bd9405afc3989e03cfa9a6b4a4). But I don't think the error description is useful. You can check the device log (using `dlogutil CAPI_LOCATION_MANAGER` in the sdb shell or Device Manager) for any details.